# Is it possible in drupal to delete a node without displaying the default drupal_set_message

Tags: drupal

**I would like to be able to programmatic-ally delete a node:**

```
node_delete(N);
```

**Without getting something like the following message when the page is refreshed:**

> Document Delivery Request Sather,
>   Kinzer-Tevaris v. Smith, Death has
>   been deleted

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `drupal_get_messages` before the end of your script it will reset the messages queue.

Check out the documentation [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_messages).

Answer (score 1):

For non-developers I created the Rules integrated "[better messages](http://drupal.org/project/rules_better_message)" module, which adds the clean action.
So if you want to do the same nicely, you can use the module.

Regards,
Shushu